# Intel Pro/1000 EB on-board interface runs at 100 Mb/s not 1 Gp/s

Tags: 20.04, intel, e1000

This seems to be the same as another question asked yesterday.

I’m having a problem with getting an Intel gigabit interface to operate at full speed.

System is a Supermicro X7DA8  dual Xeon.  It has two Intel “Pro/1000 EB” interfaces on the motherboard.

The system dual-boots Ubuntu Studio 20.04.4 and MS Windows 7 Pro x64.

The system is used to back up a Supermicro server with 8 4TB SAS disks.  That replaced a much older quad Opteron server where the speed was not a problem, but the new server can saturate a GigE wire most of the time and has a much larger partition, so GigE speeds are necessary.

The interface is recognized as a 1 Gb/s interface by Windows 7; I previously ran FreeBSD on it (my server back end  has been FreeBSD since the early 1990’s) and that always connected at 1 Gb/s.

The other question had a request to run `ethtool`:

```
ethtool enp6s0f1
Settings for enp6s0f1:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: on (auto)
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

I ran the usual `lshw` and `dmesg` and discovered in the `dmesg` that the following:

```
[52.221560] e1000e 0000:06:00.1 enp6s0f1: Link Speed was downgraded by SmartSpeed.
```

The driver code seems to choose  “Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative” if the rate will be 100 Mb/s, but I haven’t looked any further (yet).

which is a signal of a bad cable.

The system was connected with a new cable labeled “CAT 6” but I bought a new “CAT 6” cable and when I installed the cable link speed was 1 GB/ps.  After a reboot it was 100 Mb/s, and disconnecting and reconnecting didn’t change that.

I tried booting the current Xubuntu version 22.04.2 and it also linked at 100 Mb/s.

I have seen a recent note that there was a kernel bug affecting the Intel chip but I haven’t seen the real announcement so far.

I’ve ordered a non-Intel GigE network card which may provide a workaround.

`dmesg` output filtered for `e1000` is:

```
[    1.274549] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
[    1.274593] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    1.280921] e1000e 0000:06:00.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.341558] e1000e 0000:06:00.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x4) 00:30:48:7e:cb:cc
[    1.341577] e1000e 0000:06:00.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.341658] e1000e 0000:06:00.0 eth0: MAC: 5, PHY: 5, PBA No: 2050FF-0FF
[    1.341918] e1000e 0000:06:00.1: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.382426] e1000e 0000:06:00.1 eth1: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x4) 00:30:48:7e:cb:cd
[    1.382431] e1000e 0000:06:00.1 eth1: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.382511] e1000e 0000:06:00.1 eth1: MAC: 5, PHY: 5, PBA No: 2050FF-0FF
[    1.384825] e1000e 0000:06:00.1 enp6s0f1: renamed from eth1
[    1.399218] e1000e 0000:06:00.0 enp6s0f0: renamed from eth0
[   52.221436] e1000e 0000:06:00.1 enp6s0f1: NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   52.221560] e1000e 0000:06:00.1 enp6s0f1: Link Speed was downgraded by SmartSpeed
[   52.221563] e1000e 0000:06:00.1 enp6s0f1: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
```

`sudo lshw -C net` yields

```
 *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 80003ES2LAN Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0f0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:30:48:7e:cb:cc
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-70-lowlatency firmware=2.1-12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:24 memory:d2220000-d223ffff memory:d2200000-d221ffff ioport:4000(size=32) memory:d2280000-d228ffff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 80003ES2LAN Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.1
       logical name: enp6s0f1
       version: 01
       serial: 00:30:48:7e:cb:cd
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-70-lowlatency duplex=full firmware=2.1-12 ip=192.168.0.25 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:26 memory:d2260000-d227ffff memory:d2240000-d225ffff ioport:4020(size=32) memory:d2290000-d229ffff
```

Comment: There was a just reported bug in the e1000e driver, but it was for a 60% max, not 10% like you report. https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/software/general-linux-open-source/1383826-intel-i219-lm-had-only-been-running-at-~60-of-maximum-speed-due-to-linux-driver-bug

Comment: Booted the system from the FreeBSD 13.1 DVD; active Ethernet interface connected at 1 Gb/s with no issues.  Given that MS Windows 7 and FreeBSD 13.1 connect at 1 Gb/s but both Ubuntu Studio 20.04 and Xubuntu 22.04 at 100 Mb/s this would seem to suggest an Ubuntu issue.  I will be trying to work around this with a non-Intel Ethernet card.

Comment: Using "ethtool" I have reset the speed to 1 Gp/s full duplex; rsync is running at 15 Mb/s with a few peaks to 60 Mb/s which is more than before but much slower than rsync between the old FreeBSD server and the new one.  The backup system is an Ubuntu Studio desktop which I can repurpose to FreeBSD if necessary but I'd have to bring up a new workstation.  I have a generic Ethernet and a Broadcom Ethernet card on the way, so I will wait until those fail before repurposing.

Comment: Problem solved by a $10 purchase of a Broadcomm PCI-X GigE Ethernet card.  System now copying at 100 Mb/s with peaks to 200 Mb/s (buffering?).  My suspicion is that the specific chip used on the Supermicro X7DAE board was never added to the driver.  If I find the chip ID I'll ask again since it's a common chip in server/workstation motherboards.

Comment: You may answer your own question, and if upvoted, mark it as solved -- gaining some rep. points and helping others with the problem.